# Updating Gtk container when adding widgets

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I've got some code which populates a GtkVBox with new widgets from some data, after the UI is initially built.

So there's some code which runs later looking something like this:

```
gchar* str = "something or other";
ascii_labels [i] = gtk_label_new (NULL);
gtk_label_set_markup (GTK_LABEL (ascii_labels [i]), str);

ascii_event_boxes [i] = gtk_event_box_new ();

gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (ascii_event_boxes [i]),
                   ascii_labels [i]);

gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (ascii_box),
                    ascii_event_boxes [i],
                    FALSE, FALSE, 0);
```

in some loop. A bit later I have

```
gtk_widget_show_all (ascii_box);
```

to set visibility. This seems to work, in that when I run the resulting application with GtkParasite, I can see the widgets nested correctly in the Widget Tree and they are set to be visible.

Unfortunately, they don't actually appear in the application's window! The reason I think I'm missing some sort of "update yourself please" call is that if I toggle the visibility of one of those widgets from the GtkParasite tool, all the other widgets that were missing magically appear!

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Well, for the small code samples, you're putting in your question unless you put something inside that GtkEventBox it won't show nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I've added the previous couple of lines now. `ascii_labels` and `ascii_event_boxes` are actually both of type `std::vector<GtkWidget*>`, but I think that should be irrelevant. The label is definitely inserted correctly: see the GtkParasite comment slightly below the code.

Answer (score 1):

The packing looks good, but what we need here is to know what `ascii_labels` contains, and how it's defined. The problem is not visibility, as `gtk_widget_show_all` takes care of that for you.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm editing the question to make more sense now.